# Swift 4.0 Delayed Launch Screen Causes Items to disappear

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am creating an app with Swift 4.0 and I am trying to delay the launch screen. The initial screen will sleep for 2 seconds, then the "a FusionPointInc application" label will disappear and the screen will stay at the red curtain background image (the second image). It will stay there and won't show the second screen (the Theater Stages Throughout History screen)

Here is my code for the initial screen:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sleep(2)

    showNavController()
}

func showNavController() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMainView", sender: self)
}
```

[image: ThreeImages]
[image: ImageThatHasNoLabel]

More code for the initial screen (will transition to the second screen):

`class showMainView: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSegue", sender: self)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

This screen will open and when prompted to segue, the screen will only show the background (the second picture).

The middle screen code is in the ViewController.swift file and it has no actual code in it (just the pre-formatted base code)

I tested when I delete the initial screen, the app will load up fine. But, I wanted the initial screen to be delayed so "a FusionPointInc application" can be seen!

Comment: **Never** sleep the main thread.

Comment: Make sure you have restraints setup as well. Your items could be off screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling sleep on the main thread.

Instead, you should be doing something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2)) {
       self.showNavController()
    }
}
```

This will call `showNavController` after two seconds without issues.

Comment: [Read about DispatchQueue here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html). Also, without more code/info I cannot provide you with more help. I believe the first screenshot is in the Main storyboard, right?

Comment: Yes, the first screenshot is in the Main storyboard. I added more information throughout the post.

Comment: Can you verify that the first segue has "showMainView" as its identifier? Click on the circle in the middle of the arrow from the first screen to the second, and you should see the identifier in the Attributes Inspector. I can see you have a class named showMainView, but that isn't the same thing as a segue identifier.

Comment: I changed the name of the segue identifier. Should it be the same as the class?

Comment: No. It should only be unique if a view controller has multiple segues going out of it. Also as a suggestion, class names should start with an uppercase letter so that they are easily distinguished from variables.